# Is there a proxy server/apache module I can install that will convert an XML SOAP response to JSON?

Tags: javascript, apache, json, soap, proxy

I'm connecting to a remote web service which I'd prefer to call with ajax and the service (FedEx Services API) doesn't appear to support JSON formatted responses.

Is there a proxy server/apache that will convert the response from XML/SOAP into JSON so my Javascript can easily use it?

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking to go from XML to JSON?

Well I am not sure what good this would do you if the proxy is not on your server due to the same origin policy.

Anyway, here is an example of [xml-to-json](http://jsonproxy.appspot.com/proxy?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2FXML%2Fnote.xml) from http://jsonproxy.appspot.com/ of W3C's [note.xml](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Jsonproxy.appspot.com only converts the first node of a collection, so you can loose most of the data in the XML, try http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/a-better-xml-to-json-proxy/ as an alternative